# Perform patch operation on the data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Suppose I have

```
student: {
   id: 'asdj2334',
   name: 'asdcjn',
}
```

How do I send patch request/method after updating **name** of the object. suppose **axios.patch()**
Update1: I did the same as said below and I am getting success but it is not being updated on serve.

```
patchMedication (medication) {
    /* eslint-disable */
    console.log(medication)
    return API.patch('/medicationRegisters/' + medication.id, {medication})
        .then(response => {
            return response.data
        })
},
```

on console I get : 
[image]

And after success it is not updated[image]

Comment: patch request ? Do you use axios ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 patch method, yes I am using axios

Comment: then laravel your server side ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use put request in your axios. see code below

```
axios.put('api endpoint'+this.student.id, this.student).then(({data}) => {
      ... success    
})
```

Comment: I did the same :
`patchMedication (medication) {
        /* eslint-disable */
        console.log(medication)
        return API.patch('/medicationRegisters/' + medication.id, {medication})
            .then(response => {
                return response.data
            })
    },`
It is success but it is not being updated on server

Comment: what is your route in your server ?

Comment: Route to server means ?

Comment: Sorry i didnot understand

Comment: show also your route used and the method in your controller

Comment: I am handling only the frontend, I only have API. I donot have controller implementation

Comment: btw what is medication ? is it the student ?

Comment: in your API.patch('/medicationRegisters/' + medication.id, {medication}), it should be API.patch('/medicationRegisters/' + medication.id, medication) since medication is already an object